# Database user specified as a definer

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, view

I have a view in my database. problem is below

Error
SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `lumiin_crm_prod`.`v_contact` 
LIMIT 1 ;
```

MySQL said:

> 1449 - The user specified as a definer ('lumicrm'@'%') does not exist

i Google for a solution

User is created for Host & not for Global.

How to create the User for Global ????

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question (directly). Try the dba SE site.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: You do not have the user `'lumicrm'@'%'` on the DB Server.

Login to MySQL and run

```
SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE user='lumicrm';
```

Let's say you see the user `'lumicrm'@'localhost'`

You have to create the user so that the view can be recognized. There are three(3) things you can try

## Try This #1

Login to MySQL as `lumicrm` and run this command

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
```

Given the output of that query:

- Copy the output of that query to a Text File
- Change the host portion of the userhost to '%';
- Copy and Paste into a MySQL Session to create the View.

## Try This #2

```
CREATE TABLE mysql.lumicrm LIKE mysql.user;
INSERT INTO mysql.lumicrm SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user='lumicrm';
UPDATE mysql.lumicrm SET host='%';
INSERT INTO mysql.user SELECT * FROM mysql.lumicrm;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
DROP TABLE mysql.lumicrm;
```

Now you have the MySQL user `'lumicrm'@'localhost'` hacked in

## Try This #3

Dump the Views to a Text File. Here are my posts on how to do this:

- `Jun 26, 2011` : [Modify DEFINER on Many Views](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/modify-definer-on-many-views/4131#4131)
- `Jan 19, 2012` : [Will mysqldump command also backup all the views that are present in DB or there is a special command for it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/will-mysqldump-command-also-backup-all-the-views-that-are-present-in-db-or-there/11006#11006)
- `May 02, 2012` : [Problem with View When Restoring a MySQL Backup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17352/problem-with-view-when-restoring-a-mysql-backup/17359#17359)

Edit the user for the View with the appropriate username. Copy the View Creation Code and Paste into a MySQL Session to create the View.

## Give it a Try !!!